# How Come public method is not printing in a IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

Shouldn't hello be printed in the console because of the return statement? The code is immediately invoked because of the () at the end so why isn't it printing?

```
var Module = (function () {

var privateMethod = function () {
// private
 };

  var someMethod = function () {
    // public
    console.log('hello');
  };

  var anotherMethod = function () {
    // public
  };

  return {
    someMethod: someMethod,
    anotherMethod: anotherMethod
  };

})();
```

Comment: It's not directly invoked because you didn't put `()` behind `someMethod: someMethod`. You would need to do `privateMethod()['someMethod']()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return {
   someMethod: someMethod,  // just a function reference
   anotherMethod: anotherMethod // again a function reference
};
```

So, you're **not** calling the function. **You're just returning the function reference attached to a property of an object.** Try to use comma operator here, which evaluates to the right most statement, whilst executing `someMethod()` function.

```
return {
 someMethod: someMethod(), someMethod, // first getting called and someMethod ref is passed to the property
 anotherMethod: anotherMethod
};
```

Comment: thanks Amit! Didn't realize that the return wasn't a part of calling the function even though Module() is followed by ().

Comment: @KennyUSC glad you realized it :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `var` keyword on the top infront of `Module`.

f you do the following in the console:

`var a = 5` // a is set to `5` yet undefined is shown in the console.

If you were to take off the `var` keyword:

`a = 5` // a is again set to `5` yet 5 is shown in the console.

But in your real code you would want to use the var keyword.

So simply put it's just the console's way of outputting like that, idk why.

Answer (score 0):

Enlighting more,

`function` itseld is object of `Function` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/x844tc74%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

So Basically you are adding a reference to object of type Function, which is not IIFE.